# How to call a fragment from non activity class in android

Tags: android

Hello friends i want to call a fragment from non activity class how is it possible

my fragment class is

```
public class JsonParsing  extends Fragment
{   
    this fragment has no ui and i want here to communicate with web server
}
```

and i want to call this fragment from a non activity class.

```
public class Ira 
{
    public void registerUser(User user,Context context)
    {
        here iwant to call and also want to send some data
    }
}
```

Comment: Does class Ira extends Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a Fragment class like any other class. Just do a

```
JsonParsing jp = new JsonParsing();
```

and you can run any public methods your fragment offers.

However, Fragments are thought to have a layout. Why don't you just use a usual Java class instead of an Android component if you have to perform non-UI operations?